# Rails Associations: Creating Orders specific to a Customer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I've read a bunch of posts relating to this, and it still has not clicked for me. I have an example that I am trying to keep as simple as possible, so that I can understand how the foreign key assignments are made.

### Assume we have 2 models...

***user.rb***

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :microposts
end
```

***micropost.rb***

```
Class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

I found some code on another post for the microposts_controller...

```
def create
   @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
   if @micropost.save
     ...
   else
     ...
   end
end
```

#### Questions

- Is 'current_user' a rails method?
- If the model was called Customer, would 'current_customer' work?
- How does the application know which User is creating the micropost? (this is probably a dumb way to word the question)

Answer (score 0):

`current_user` is typically provided by an authentication framework like Devise. It can determine that user by looking at the session that was created when they log in. And yes, if a model called Customer was created with Devise at least, current_customer would work after the "customer" logged in.

Answer (score 0):

**Answers**

1. No `current_user` is not a Rails method. It is provided by some authentication frameworks and most apps implement a `current_user` helper method that returns the current user that is usually set on a session or instance variable.
2. No, since the method is not defined by the model. `current_customer` wouldn't work. There is some ways of doing a dynamic method that given a model with another name such as `Customer` you could write a method_missing that would give the desired output but that's probably more work for what it will be used.
3. Back to question 1. the method `current_user` would return an instance of `User` which is the user currently signed in then the result would be something like `@current_user.microposts.build`

The code for current_user would usually looks something like

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
end
```

That pretty much says find a User with a `remember_token` that was previously stored in a cookie or use the `@current_user` if that has already been set.

Hope this helps!